# Twitter bootstrap grid columns touching eachother?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I am currently working on my own responsive grid with columns. I am currently using 12 columns and I give each column a multiplier of 100/12 and subtract a margin on each column. So I make each column a little bit smaller so I can fit in a margin-left and make gutters this way.

```
@for $i from 1 through $column-count {
    .column-#{$i} {
        width: (((100 + $gutter-width) / $column-count) * $i) - $gutter-width;
    }
}
```

This leaves me with something like this:

```
.column-1 {
  width: 7.41667%; }

.column-2 {
  width: 15.83333%; }

.column-3 {
  width: 24.25%; }

etc.
```

This way I can set a margin-left for each column and just remove the very first margin-left in each row with the ***first:child*** selector

Twitter bootstrap however uses a column grid where all columns touch eachother and they use padding to kind of fake column gutters. However I tried some fooling around with bootstrap and you run into a problem when you actually set like a background for a column. Immediately you can see that the columns will touch. How do people prevent this from happening?

I guess using another element would inside the column would help? This however would get a bit messier than I would like probably.

I am asking this because I am looking for a solution since my grid can only go from default columns to 100% width columns when you downsize it.

**grid:** http://titan.ravenwebdesign.nl/

I would like to be able to add something like .mobile-column-6 to certain grid columns in a manner that bootstrap has with it's grid tiers of classes.

This would be helpful in for example having 2 columns next to each other when in downsized view. Except I'm currently using rows and every first child of my row has the margin removed. So it would't work like this:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column-3 mobile-column-6"></div>
        <div class="column-3 mobile-column-6"></div>
        <div class="column-3 mobile-column-6"></div>
        <div class="column-3 mobile-column-6"></div>
    </div><!-- .row -->
```

Because of my responsive design which says that the first column will have it's margin removed I can't simply turn it into a 2 columns next to eachother design.

Hopefully somebody can help me out here although I understand this problem is extremely hard for me to explain like this.

Comment: You can't have ".mobile-column-6" as a class name. You need to remove the "."

Comment: Typo. That is not my main issue, thx for noticing though.